# Storing a pickled python object in memory for quick access

Tags: python, file, caching, persistence

I have pickled an object (myCancerObject in the example below) using the cPickle module, and I run analyses on this pickled object multiple times a day. Each time I start a separate analysis, I have to re-load the pickled object.

I was wondering if there is a way to "cache" or store this object in memory for a day so that when I call readCancerObject(), it checks to see if the pickled object that it's about to load is in memory and if it is, performs operations on the object stored in memory rather than reading it all over again each call.

Is there a pythonic way to do this? I'm hoping that caching this object will speed up the runtime of my analyses significantly.

My code looks something like this:

```
def readCancerObject():
  infile = open(object_filename,"rb")
  myCancerObject = pickle.load(infile)

  ~do iterative things on myCancerObject
```

Comment: first use `simplejson` instead of `pickle` if at all possible .. .second you should time the pickle load ... I suspect that is not the bottleneck in the program

Comment: The only method running at this point in the program is the readCancerObject() method, and it takes between 12 and 20 seconds to load the pickled object. Here is the time stamp:

    `C:\Users\...\workspace>python matrixWriter.py`
    `Enter the name of variant call file: oneVariantPerLine.pk1`
    `Time elapsed to load file: 14.639602513`

If you have any information about how to store pickled object in memory that would be much appreciated.